# Open directly Word App instead of Word Browser when i create a document

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SAAS solution of Sharepoint, when i want to create a new document template from Sharepoint, a new tab is opened with Word Browser.

I want to change this by opened directly with Word App. It's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Document libraries have a setting you can use to control this. It's in Advanced Settings:

[image]

Comment: It's not working, when i click new > word, opened again new tab on my browser with Word Web version not desktop.

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm seeing the same thing. Looks like the setting is being ignored. I've used it before without issue so I'm not sure what's changed.

Comment: Using Sharepoint Online directly not solution on promise ?